# How do I log a custom field in NLog to database using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging?

Tags: c#, logging, nlog, asp.net-core-3.1, microsoft-extensions-logging

I am using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging together with NLog. My app is .NET Core 3.1.

I would like to extend logging with custom fields.

Is it possible or will I need to use NLog directly?

```
  <parameter name="@custom_guid" layout="${custom_guid}"/>

         var config = new Dictionary<string, object>();
         config.Add("custom_guid", "test"); 
         _logger.LogInformation("Test message", config);
```

Comment: There is a wiki-page: https://github.com/NLog/NLog.Extensions.Logging/wiki/NLog-properties-with-Microsoft-Extension-Logging

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do this:

```
var config = new Dictionary<string, object>();
config.Add("custom_guid", "test");

using (_logger.BeginScope(config))
{
   _logger.LogInformation("Test message");
}
```

And use `${mdlc:custom_guid}`

Comment: I used: ${event-properties:custom_guid} and that worked for me. Thank you